# Transforming Log Values in Predicted Values (Low Predicted Scores)

Tags: multiple-regression, logarithm

I have a problem with the logging of a price variable.

The logging of the variable helps the model performance considerably. The value is positively skewed so this makes sense mathematically.

I run the models to target LN value. Then the data is scored and a predicted LN value is created. The mean predicted LN value is very close to mean actual LN value looking across a number of datasets - which makes sense.

The problem is transforming these logged values back to value is creating low predicted means since there is not as much variance to the predicted scores as the actual scores. See below for how that can work in practice. In our current model, value is very tough to predict with certainty, so predicted values tended to cluster around the mean LN value unfortunately.

I'm not 100% sure of the answer, but I see a few possibilities:

1) Since the LN value represents levels, we could apply a non-linear multiplier to pull the predicted value up.
2) Some other transformation than logging (if any are available, I don't know)
3) Treating outliers, other configurations differently. I don't think this would do much, I did some testing and nothing changed.

Actual value    LN value    Predicted LN value  Predicted value
100 4.605170186 2.868776267 17.6154484
9   2.197224577 2.866776267 17.58025271
5   1.609437912 2.867776267 17.59784176
25  3.218875825 2.867776267 17.59784176
33  3.496507561 2.867776267 17.59784176
8   2.079441542 2.867776267 17.59784176
Average 30  2.867776267 2.867776267 17.59784469